# Cold Fusion Hosting

Tags: lamp, coldfusion, dedicated-server

This may not be the place for this question but I am sure several people have some good insight to it.  I am a LAMP developer and have recently been given the task of porting a clients existing Cold Fusion site to another hosting company.  I would like to set this up on a Dedicated Virtual server preferably with Plesk / Parallels installed.  I was wondering if anyone here has had experience with Cold Fusion and if they know a good reliable host for Cold Fusion.  I really want to make the correct decision on this as my experience with CF is minimal at best.  Any and all recommendations are appreciated.

Thank you all in advance,

J

Answer (score 1):

Crystaltech.com is awsome and very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through countless CF hosting companies over the years - currently I'd highly recommend http://www.openmindhosting.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Also don't be mistaken by the Plesk Add-On which says it provides ColdFusion, it provides the ability to have ColdFusion integrated into Plesk, you still have to buy the license. HostNexus provides Linux ColdFusion hosting at a reasonable price.